# Power mockito mock static calling actual method

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

```
 private void mockStorageServiceFactory(StorageGroupService storageGroupService)
        throws StorageServiceException {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(StorageServiceFactory.class);
    PowerMockito.when(StorageServiceFactory.getContainerNameForPartner(anyLong()))
        .thenReturn("dummyName");
}
```

Actual method is getting called at 3rd line (`when().thenReturn()`).
I have already added `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PrepareForTest` annotations.
Why actual method is called? I tried `PowerMockito.doReturn` also, but getting same issue.

Comment: You could perhaps add more details (i.e. the actual test case) to your question. For example; you wrote "I have already added @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) and @PrepareForTest annotations" ... but withou showing us the actual test case we cannot know whether you applied `@PrepareForTest` to `StorageServiceFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was running the test case from main method. When i ran it as JUNIT, it is working.